# Get userInfo from Instagram in android

Tags: android, instagram

I am integrating Instagram in my android app. I am able to get authetication and token from Instagram API. Now what I am looking for is userinfo. As soon as user is authenticated I want his userinfo like username,name etc. Any idea how to get it ? I tried several ways but didnt able to achieve it.

I tried this example https://github.com/poller/instagram-demo-for-android

Comment: Please read the [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/)

Comment: Found answer by my self. Here it is to help other folks Instagram igram = new Instagram(clientId, clientSecret, accessToken,
    redirectUri); and igram.getUserInfo("self")

Answer (score 1):

Get basic information about a user. To get information about the owner of the access token, you can use self instead of the user-id.

Link for Documentation is :

https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

Use this API  :

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN](https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/%7Buser-id%7D/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN)

Response contains information about that particular user requested by passing ID :

```
{
"data": {
    "id": "1574083",
    "username": "snoopdogg",
    "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
    "profile_picture": "url of picture",
    "bio": "This is my bio",
    "website": "website of that user",
    "counts": {
        "media": 1320,
        "follows": 420,
        "followed_by": 3410
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply pass your access token to this url. And you will get the logged user information of the Instagram.

[https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=YOUR-ACCESS-TOKEN]

this will return the user information like the above @Heena Arora mentioned.
And also she mentioned about retrieving the user information for the particular user by id.